# Change ticker of tradingview widget with an interval

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, tradingview-api

It's probably really easy but I just can't figure out how to change the ticker symbol in the Tradingview widget. I want the chart to change to the tickers in a array i got. The chart needs to change every 30 seconds with a new ticker and do that forever.

This is what I got so far:

```html
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_5889e"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-RIG/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">RIG</span> <span class="blue-text">chart</span> by TradingView</a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0
    function createchart(){
      var companies = ['NYSE:SDRL','NYSE:RIG','CHXEUR:SEVDRO','NYSE:TK','CHXEUR:GBBP']
      new TradingView.widget(
      {
      "width": 980,
      "height": 610,
      "symbol": companies[i],
      "interval": "15",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "Light",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "hide_top_toolbar": true,
      "save_image": false,
      "hideideas": true,
      "container_id": "tradingview_5889e"
      }
      );
      i++;

    }

    setInterval(createchart(),10000)

    </script>
  </div>
```

Hope you guys can help me out. Been struggeling on this for way too long.

Comment: `setInterval(createchart,10000)` will work

Comment: it would be much more efficient if you moved the unchanging var `companies` outside of the `createchart()` function, assign your TV.widget to a variable, finally have another function that gets called by setInterval. This extra function simply calls `widget_variable.setSymbol(symbol, interval, [callback])` avoiding the chart from reinitialising every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
setInterval(function(){
  createchart()
}, 10000);
```

For some reasons it usually doesnt work the other way

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
Looks like setInterval requires for you to define the function that it will call every time the interval is up. Check w3s, they might have something more on this

Comment: This works thanks a lot! I thought i had the syntax right, but i guess not.

Comment: if you have a function that doesn't need to accept args (as you do) then you call the function name without the () as Artem mentioned above, otherwise if your called function does need args you have to wrap it in an anon function as per this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this also

```
setInterval(createchart, 10000);
```